# New to Programming and needing a bit of help understanding the concept behind vectors

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble understanding the following question I came across in class.

"Create a row vector using variable names theTime, StartTime, IncrementTime and EndTime. THe values of theTime are 0, 0.25, 0.5, ... 1.25."

I understand how to setup the vector, but I am receiving an error message when I run the script that I haven't setup an assignment statement for the "start value, increment value or end value".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

### Creating The Vector:

It's always good to get the fundamentals right. The first step is to initialize each variable `StartTime`,`IncrementTime` and `EndTime`. Creating the vector can be done by using colons, `:` to separate the three parameters dictating the starting value, increment value and end value. The brackets `()` used when creating the vector are not compulsory but can give a nice touch.

### Displaying The Vector:

To display the row vector in the command window I added the last line of code without a semi-colon, `;` to not suppress the output. Alternatively, the `disp()` function or workspace window can used to view the vector, `theTime` you just created.

[image: Creating Vectors Diagram]

```
StartTime = 0;
IncrementTime = 0.25;
EndTime = 1.25;

theTime = (StartTime:IncrementTime:EndTime);
theTime
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That is actually so simple to understand, I don't know why it wasn't explained like that in class.